# mutiple tags, how to find object with the exact tags specfied?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, tagging

I have implemented a tagging system, but I want to be able to exclude all objects that do not only have the tags specified

For example I have a tag Archer, and an object with the tags Archer, Human, so when I search for Archer, the object shouldnt appear, unless I search for both Archer and Human

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I managed to solve it by using intersection

Comment: If you anser your question yourself, please show how you did it.